# Loop through columns and paste an array formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a problem to loop through a certain number of columns and paste in an array formula. For every new column, I have to change the formula to reflect that column address. However, when I try to run it now, I keep getting a 1004 (select method of range class failed) error. Here is what I have written:

```
Sub Testlee()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim colStr As String

LastColumn = 10
For i = 1 To LastColumn
colStr = Replace(Split(Columns(i).Address, ":")(0), "$", "")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Validation").Range(colStr & "2:" & colStr &  "500").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IF(LEN(Agent1!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500) + LEN(Agent2!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500) = 0,"""",(IF(Agent1!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500=Agent2!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500, ""YES"", Agent1!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500&""||""&Agent2!" & colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500)))"

Next i

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated : )

Update: I was able to get it working using a combination of the two approaches. Here is the code that works:

```
For i = 1 To LastColumn
colStr = Replace(Split(Columns(i).Address, ":")(0), "$", "")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Validation").Range("A2:A500")
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Validation").Range(colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500").FormulaArray = "=IF(LEN(Agent1!RC:R[498]C)+LEN(Agent2!RC:R[498]C) = 0,"""",(IF(Agent1!RC:R[498]C=Agent2!RC:R[498]C, ""YES"", Agent1!RC:R[498]C&""||""&Agent2!RC:R[498]C)))"
    End With
Next i
```

Thank to everyone for their help!

Comment: did you use the R1C1 reference style?

Comment: You can `Select` cells only in active sheet. You don't need select at all [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251)

Comment: Hi BrakNicku, I tried not using Select, and just doing having it as Sheets(Range).FormulaArray = "Formula" but it didn't work either.

Comment: psychicebola, I didn't use R1C1 reference in the formula. I'm not sure how to implement that in an array formula with changing columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Sub MM()

Const LastCol As Integer = 10 '// Column number to extend to

With Sheets("Data Validation").Range("A2:A500")
    .Resize(500, LastCol).FormulaArray = "=IF(LEN(Agent1!RC:R[498]C)+LEN(Agent2!RC:R[498]C) = 0,"""",(IF(Agent1!RC:R[498]C=Agent2!RC:R[498]C, ""YES"", Agent1!RC:R[498]C&""||""&Agent2!RC:R[498]C)))"
End With

End Sub
```

- Use [R1C1 Notation](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33521) to make the formula relevant to each cell without looping.
- Also, you can use `Resize()` method to *resize* an existing range - again, saves looping. [Info on Resize method here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274.aspx)
- Finally, as already mentioned - 99.99% of the time there is no need to `.Select` anything in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) - you can access an object's properties and methods directly without making it the `Selection`

Comment: Hi @Macro Man, thanks for the advice! I think you're right that I need to use R1C1, but when I implement it in this way: 
   
With Sheets("Data Validation").Range("A2:A500")
    .Resize(500, LastCol).FormulaArray = "=IF(LEN(Agent1!RC:R[498]C)+LEN(Agent2!RC:R[498]C) = 0,"""",(IF(Agent1!RC:R[498]C=Agent2!RC:R[498]C, ""YES"", Agent1!RC:R[498]C&""||""&Agent2!RC:R[498]C)))"

Then I end up with a range of A500:J with exactly the same formula (in this case the R1C1 evaluates to A2:A500). It doesn't seem to change according to the column.

Comment: Hi @Macro Man I put in the R1C1 and it still only copies in the same formula in the range A2:J500.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you're probably selecting the columns of Sheets 'Data Validation' while the active sheet is another worksheet.

You need to activate Data Validations Sheet first which means you add a line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Validation").Select
```

before the line

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Validation").Range(colStr & "2:" & colStr & "500").Select
```

This is provided you don't need to run anymore code which uses the current activesheet.